# itext7-dotnet | How to generate a PDF containing table data with table header row in all the pages of PDF

Tags: itext, row, pdf-generation, itext7, tableheader

Looking for the ability to generate the PDF file using iText7-dotnet from CSV content with the table header row in all the pages of PDF where the table data spans.

Appreciate any guidance on the same.
Thanks in advance!

Currently, able to the get the table header row in the first page of PDF but unable to get the same in the remaining pages of PDF content.